# Accessing a List object from a List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, object

I have a list of several points of service in a List.

Within the **PointsOfServices** there is another object named **Orders**. How do i go about getting access to the Orders object to use it's data alongside the PointsOfService data?

Thanks

[image: List question]

Edit: I want to be able to use this data to produce a GridView that will enable me to display both data from PointOfServices and Orders.

Will i be able to use a Future for this and FutureBuilder when creating the GridView?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access it using the index

```
print(mainList[0].orders[0].id);
```

Will print the first pointOfService's first order's Id

Note: here mainList is the name of the list that contains all pointOfService and i assumed that you have id in each order

Comment: This is a great help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear as of what you want to exactly achieve, but to access `list` inside `list` , you can refer this ,

```
class PointOfService {
  final String name;
  final List<Order> orders;
  PointOfService({this.name, this.orders});
}

class Order {
  final String name;
  Order({this.name});
}

void main() {
  List<PointOfService> pointofServices = [
    PointOfService(
        name: "PointOfService 1",
        orders: [
          Order(name: "Order 1"),
          Order(name: "Order 2"),
        ]),
    PointOfService(
        name: "PointOfService 2",
        orders: [
          Order(name: "Order 3"),
          Order(name: "Order 4"),
        ])
  ];

  for (var pointOfService in pointofServices) {
    print("PointOfService name: ${pointOfService.name}");
    for (var order in pointOfService.orders) {
      print("Order name: ${order.name}");
    }
  }
}
```

This will output

```
PointOfService name: PointOfService 1
Order name: Order 1
Order name: Order 2
PointOfService name: PointOfService 2
Order name: Order 3
Order name: Order 4
```

---

###### Edit

For `GridView` you can do something like:

```
FutureBuilder<List<PointOfService>>(
    future: < Your future here >
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return  GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.pointOfServices.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Order order = snapshot.data!.pointOfServices[index];
                return Column(
                       children:[
                           Text(order['name']),// You can access this way
                       );
              );
            }),
        } else {
        return Text("No data");
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: This is a great help, thank you.  I have updated my question with a tad more detail.

Comment: @DeanBall I have updated my post to provide the possible way to reach your goal, make changes to the code provided according to your requirements, hope it helps!!

Comment: That is a help too, so i thank you for that. Bit of a digression to my original question but i'm not sure how to get the orders from the PointOfServices in my Future. Do i just return the PointOfServices list and that will allow me access to my Orders? Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly you need to get just the list of `PointOfServices` from the future,from there you can access the orders as mentioned in the code, then rest you can follow th code structure that i have provided, make sure you change my code to your requirements, it is just a template providing the structure of using gridview with the futureBuilder.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I'm new to all this, as you can see :) If i need to filter some data, can i still do that too? Using the where?  So, Orders may container data i don't want them to see if the date doesn't equal Today.